# Seeking a GUI auto-format feature for T-SQL

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, reformat

Is there a freely available GUI tool that will allow interaction with Microsoft SQL Server (via T-SQL) that provides an auto-format feature?

I constantly find myself writing queries in SQL Query Analyzer (Microsoft’s standard GUI tool for T-SQL) and cutting/pasting the whole thing into SQLyog (a GUI tool for MySQL), where I can press F12 and have it reformatted into an easily readable, industry standard format.  I then cut/paste this back into Query Analyzer to execute.  I do this all the time at work and haven’t been able to find an alternative.

I realize that SQLyog is no longer free software, but what I’m looking for is a specific alternative to a MS SQL Server interface (with auto-formatting).  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't know of one but SQL Query Analyzer hasn't been the "standard GUI tool for T-SQL" since about 2005. Though it doesn't do auto-formatting, I like using LINQpad. It can issue direct SQL, it doesn't need to use LINQ.

Comment: @Josh Uh, besides LINQPad (which is alright, I suppose), what am I missing out on? I'm _still_ using the Enterprise Manager for just about everything. What better tools are there?

Comment: I guess you're on SQL 2000 then? I don't know. It's kinda old. Maybe Red Gate has something better. Why don't you download a trial of SQL 2008 and look at its management tools. They are much better than Enterprise Manager IMO. Particularly since it uses the same code editor as Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The [SSMS Tools Pack.](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/)

Comment: @marc_s: question is not tagged as such.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback.  The SSMS Tools Pack is an add-on to SSMS/SQL Server 2005+ and so it’s not technically free, but this is an acceptable answer to my question.  Have to accept that working in a proprietary extension of SQL (here T-SQL) locks us into certain tools.  I'm going to continue using SQLyog to format my sql statements.  The formatting of SQLyog isn’t an industry-standard anyway, I just think it’s the most clear and easily readable format I’ve come across, and it’s what my company uses as a format style, so I’m biased.)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dvanaria: Hi. The SSMS Tools pack is currently free (there is a donation link, but it is free...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use "SQL Query Analyzer" which is SQL Server 2000 then you have only Red Gate as an option AFAIK.

For SSMS/SQL Server 2005+ there is the SSMS tools pack as mentioned

Edit: [SQuirreL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) has [formatting and other plugins](http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=plugins) that will be better than SSMS tools pack